# Netbeans maven hot deploy

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish

So I have imported a project to netbeans. I am using jsf and xhtml pages. I have already deployed the project on Glassfish using maven.

When I make changes to xhtml pages, it doesn't reflect on UI. So I have gone to the project properties->compile-> compile on save for both application and ... .

But still any changes I make to code is not reflecting in UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel) can help here. It handles Java code changes as well as static resources. It has even integration with all the major frameworks out there.

Comment: Could you suggest any way to make JRebel work when using Project Stage `production` ? Actually it works but it then sets the project stage to `development` by itself.

Comment: JRebel is not intended to be used in production. JRebel is a development tool, mostly used in conjunction with the IDE, and the user agreement does't allow it for use to update live systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Set your PROJECT_STAGE = Development

Comment: Tnx I ll try that and get back to you!